# Should I read もつれて or つれて in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> カン蛙も仕方なく、ルラ蛙もつれて、新婚旅行に出かけました。

Do I have to read ルラ蛙も　連{つ}れて OR ルラ蛙　縺{もつ}れて?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is も連れて. So here is meant "taking ルラ蛙 too".

If 縺{もつ}れて is used, it would require a particle like AがB**と**縺れて.